# error: deployment "deployment" exceeded its progress deadline

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubectl

```
Run ./deploy-scripts/deploy.sh
***
{
    "UserId": "AROAYM5RD5YROQ3NBRSBO:git-actions-pipeline",
    "Account": "***",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/github-action-role/git-actions-pipeline"
}
Added new context arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:***:cluster/eks-cluster-promise-development to /home/runner/.kube/config
1.2.0.d1113dd69b26e484f2f90ea477723ca25aeebb2b: Pulling from pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer
1efc276f4ff9: Pulling fs layer
a2f2f93da482: Pulling fs layer
12cca292b13c: Pulling fs layer
d73cf48caaac: Pulling fs layer
120b356d2dd8: Pulling fs layer
87f53b4dc065: Pulling fs layer
0320d53e11e9: Pulling fs layer
32c7824395b2: Pulling fs layer
120b356d2dd8: Waiting
d73cf48caaac: Waiting
87f53b4dc065: Waiting
0320d53e11e9: Waiting
32c7824395b2: Waiting
12cca292b13c: Download complete
a2f2f93da482: Download complete
1efc276f4ff9: Verifying Checksum
1efc276f4ff9: Download complete
d73cf48caaac: Verifying Checksum
d73cf48caaac: Download complete
87f53b4dc065: Verifying Checksum
87f53b4dc065: Download complete
0320d53e11e9: Verifying Checksum
0320d53e11e9: Download complete
120b356d2dd8: Verifying Checksum
120b356d2dd8: Download complete
32c7824395b2: Verifying Checksum
32c7824395b2: Download complete
1efc276f4ff9: Pull complete
a2f2f93da482: Pull complete
12cca292b13c: Pull complete
d73cf48caaac: Pull complete
120b356d2dd8: Pull complete
87f53b4dc065: Pull complete
0320d53e11e9: Pull complete
32c7824395b2: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7d4041b09d57ce92706faed94b03871b4fb1c8614f01d60879ee3bf51c87b2b4
Status: Downloaded newer image for ***/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer:1.2.0.d1113dd69b26e484f2f90ea477723ca25aeebb2b
***/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer:1.2.0.d1113dd69b26e484f2f90ea477723ca25aeebb2b
The push refers to repository [***/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer]
ecfa0bceb278: Preparing
8524505bb0dd: Preparing
866c9aa9ba77: Preparing
a54187be2b77: Preparing
d7802b8508af: Preparing
e3abdc2e9252: Preparing
eafe6e032dbd: Preparing
92a4e8a3140f: Preparing
e3abdc2e9252: Waiting
eafe6e032dbd: Waiting
92a4e8a3140f: Waiting
ecfa0bceb278: Layer already exists
a54187be2b77: Layer already exists
866c9aa9ba77: Layer already exists
d7802b8508af: Layer already exists
8524505bb0dd: Layer already exists
e3abdc2e9252: Layer already exists
92a4e8a3140f: Layer already exists
eafe6e032dbd: Layer already exists
1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.dev: digest: sha256:7d4041b09d57ce92706faed94b03871b4fb1c8614f01d60879ee3bf51c87b2b4 size: 1998
***/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.dev
Currently running deployment color : blue
Error: no matches found
deployment.apps/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer-green created
Waiting for deployment "pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer-green" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
error: deployment "pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer-green" exceeded its progress deadline
deployment.apps "pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer-green" deleted
./deploy-scripts/deploy.sh: line 124: ./kub-errornous-command-to-fail: No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

these are the error logs while deploying in eks cluster.
below is yaml config details

```
Name:             pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer-blue-7477c57685-rlz28
Namespace:        dev
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             ip-10-124-197-214.ec2.internal/10.124.197.214
Start Time:       Thu, 08 Jun 2023 11:48:26 +0530
Labels:           application=promise-engine
                  color=blue
                  pod-template-hash=7477c57685
                  uservice=pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer
                  version=1.2.0
Annotations:      kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:           Running
IP:               10.124.197.50
IPs:
  IP:           10.124.197.50
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer-blue-7477c57685
Containers:
  pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer:
    Container ID:   docker://587936e5deb9ae8ffc6b545846957911fe5466270a3f35f531809601e1ed8b51
    Image:          577507683874.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.dev
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://577507683874.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer@sha256:7d4041b09d57ce92706faed94b03871b4fb1c8614f01d60879ee3bf51c87b2b4
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Thu, 22 Jun 2023 21:48:55 +0530
      Finished:     Thu, 22 Jun 2023 21:49:10 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  3963
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  512Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
      memory:   512Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:8080/actuator/health delay=200s timeout=10s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:8080/actuator/health delay=100s timeout=10s period=30s #success=1 #failure=1
    Startup:    http-get http://:8080/actuator/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=60
    Environment:
      CLUSTER_NAME:            eks-cluster-promise-development
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE:  dev
      SERVICE_NAME:            pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer
      SERVICE_VERSION:         1.2.0
      NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME:      pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer
      NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY:   8b770649bafe38c4a353997d71d0b5bbFFFFNRAL
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-fhw8x (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-fhw8x:
    Type:                     Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:   3607
    ConfigMapName:            kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:        <nil>
    DownwardAPI:              true
QoS Class:                    Burstable
Node-Selectors:               <none>
Tolerations:                  node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                              node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Topology Spread Constraints:  topology.kubernetes.io/zone:ScheduleAnyway when max skew 1 is exceeded for selector color=blue,uservice=pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Normal   Pulling  8m8s (x3963 over 14d)  kubelet  Pulling image "577507683874.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.dev"
  Warning  BackOff  3m (x95901 over 14d)   kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

I am facing an issue while deploying the application and the current pod status is in crashloop backoff status because of some java illegal exception. I added snapshot of error log while deploying.

[this is snapfhot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flxjc.png)

the below are logs of pod

{"@timestamp":"2023-06-23T05:44:04.687Z","@version":"1","message":"Starting StockUpdatesApplication using Java 11.0.16 on pe-cache-atp-app-stock-updates-producer-blue-7477c57685-rlz28 with PID 7 (/app.jar started by root in /)","logger_name":"com.hbc.StockUpdatesApplication","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-06-23T05:44:04.752Z","@version":"1","message":"The following 1 profile is active: "dev"","logger_name":"com.hbc.StockUpdatesApplication","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
{"@timestamp":"2023-06-23T05:44:07.194Z","@version":"1","message":"Application run failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service id not legal hostname (${auth-token.name})\n\tat org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.getName(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:111)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.getName(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:282)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.getName(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:270)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.getContextId(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:288)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClient(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:213)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerFeignClients(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:202)\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:151)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:86)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)\n\tat java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)\n\tat org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)\n\tat com.hbc.StockUpdatesApplication.main(StockUpdatesApplication.java:11)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)\n"}

this is a spring application right now not able to deploy new code to eks cluster so even to resolve the error without new deployment I am not able to do any try.

Comment: The diagnostics you've shown don't actually say more than that the main container process exited with status 1.  What's inside the container?  Does it run in plain Docker or another simpler environment?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] (making sure to include details like logs in plain text, not images)?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze Thanks for looking into this, I added pod logs now can please take a look now. Mainly the issue I am getting that, not able to deploy updates on eks cluster